# How to test whether an image is already in cache?

Tags: jquery, image, optimization, coldfusion, background-image

I am using ColdFusion 10 and jQuery 1.7.1 and Bootstrap.

I am developing a web site that has a lot of large, high-quality images on the home page. On the home page, there is an image carousel that pulls ten high quality images from a database. The images can be 1 meg each. The carousel images aren't my problem (right now), but it has something to do with it.

The problem I am trying to address right now is that I use a high quality background image that I want to continue using, it's about 180k. If I have the background in cache on the home page, I want to use it. If not, then I don't want to use it on the home page. I'll load it from a different page. When the user returns to the home page, and the background image is in cache, I want to use it.

Can I test whether an image is already in cache and if so, dynamically load or NOT load based on that?

You can see the home page here:

```
http://flyingpiston2012-com.securec37.ezhostingserver.com/
```

Answer (score 1):

I don't think that there is a way to test if an image is in your browser cache.

However, one way that you could solve this problem is by using [jQuery's .load() event](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/). When an image is loaded, put the image ID (or filename) into localStorage (or a cookie). You can then test this variable to see if the image has been loaded.

Example of setting the localStorage variable for your images:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   $('.hiResImg').load(function () {
      var imgSrc = $(this).attr('src');
      var loadedImgs = localStorage.getItem("loadedImgs");

      loadedImgs = loadedImgs || [];

      loadedImgs.push(imgSrc);

      localStorage.setItem("loadedImgs", loadedImgs);
   });
});
```

Example of testing for and loading the image:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var loadedImgs = localStorage.getItem("loadedImgs").split(',');

   var imagePath = "http://localhost/path/to/someImg.jpg";

   if ($.inArray(imagePath, loadedImgs) > -1) {
      $('body').css('background-image', 'url(' + imagePath + ')');
   }
});
```

Note: this code has not been fully tested.

Comment: That sounds like a good idea! I think I will move forward with this approach.

Answer (score 0):

It may or may not be an option depending on the browser support you requre, but you could store it in the browser's localStorage using a DataURL.

Here's a Mozilla article covering this topic: http://hacks.mozilla.org/2012/02/saving-images-and-files-in-localstorage/

You should also be aware that localStorage does have a size limit, which I believe is typically 5MB for a given domain.  This shouldn't be an issue with your 180KB background image, but depending on browser settings and other pages/sites on the domain there is the chance it may be an issue.